# Average of top counts and use it in conditional prompts in Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Im using Cognos 10.2.1 
My question has two parts to it.

1. How to calculate an average of top 20 count.
2. Can I use this to conditional format my bar chart.

I did use feeder queries and tried to get the average of top counts but am now receiving a cross join error :(

Please help me on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had feed a query into another query

Step 1 : FIrst query had the result set( rank of top 20 count) + data item containing integer 1
Step 2: Created another query with just one data item containing just integer 1

We need this data item to join and feed it to another query

Step 3: Join these query and edit relationship to join it on the data item containing integer 1 to feed it into another query

Step 4: The new query now will just have the data set as its source.

P.S I had to create a data item containing integer 1 in the final query to work (No idea why cognos did it)

AFter this I was able to use this in the conditional formatting.
Encountered errors like not able to get master detail relationship which I resolved using this : https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21339010

This thread helped me a lot: 
http://www.cognoise.com/index.php?topic=9586.0